# URL Rewrite causing javascript issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

When I have the below rules applied in my web.config for URL rewriting, click events do not get fired on link buttons that have field validators in the form. When the below code is removed, all works fine. Any ideas how I can get this working? The error I get when clicking a linkbutton is - JavaScript runtime error: 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Rule 1 for StaticRewrites" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: Do you have any 404 on the dev console ?

Comment: No 404 errors on IE dev console.